# Sharepoint ADFS Claims based auth trying auth on wrong server

Tags: claims-based-auth, adfs

Lab Environment: Two Stand-alone SharePoint 2016 VM servers.  One was initially set up for testing and proof of concept (Server A).  Once the concept was proven viable, I was tasked with creating a second server (Server B), a duplicate of the first.  I restored the image of the first server to the second server and began to make the necessary changes (different domain).  Everything is up and running with the exception of AFDS Claims-based Authentication.  The second server (Server B) displays the choice for Windows Login or ADFS Login, but when you select ADFS login, it takes me to the original server (Server A) login screen and tries to auth.  I have looked everywhere and can not seem to find where I need to make the required changes on Server B to auth locally instead of trying Server A.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you attempted to use an image of a SharePoint server after running the Config Wizard, you're in unsupported territory and likely still attached to the previous SQL Server.

It sounds like you should build a new farm from scratch and replicate your settings instead.

However, take care in decomm'ing your cloned member as this may remove the "only" SharePoint server from your original farm. I would suggest building a second server, again from scratch, on your original test farm prior to removing your cloned server. Your original test server will likely become disconnected.

Comment: Well I am definately connected to the correct SQL Server.  Server A is shutdown and Server B works fine as long as I login using Windows Auth.  I realize I am in uncharted waters and unsupported territory.  That was one of the reasons for this project. To see if it could be done.  I have been able to make all aspects of the server function with the exception of the Claims-based auth (trying to go to Server A).  I'm sure there is a way, I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: It's not supported. You should start with a new farm. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/deploy-sharepoint-virtual-machines

Comment: Solution is: $ti = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer ; $ti.ProviderUri = ‘https://ADFS FQDN/adfs/ls‘ ; $ti.update()